# sqlite convert Jdn to unixepoch

Tags: java, sqlite, milliseconds, julian-date

I have a column of date in `jdn` format. I want to migrate my date format from jdn to Java `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` that is equal to sqlite `unixepoch`.

here is sample migration code.

```
ALTER TABLE  TABLE_TIMES  ADD COLUMN  millies INTEGER
UPDATE TABLE_TIMES SET millies = ????
-- ALTER TABLE for DELETE COLUMN jdn
```

how i can convert `jdn` to `unixepoch`. what should i use instead of `????`?

Comment: SQLite's `unixepoch` is not milliseconds.

Comment: millisecond is not important, we can put 000 to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's built-in [date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) already support Julian day numbers.
To output a `unixepoch` value, use the `%s` format of `strftime`.
To convert from seconds to milliseconds, multiply by 1000:

```sql
UPDATE Table_Times SET millies = strftime('%s', jdn) * 1000
```